# Remote Debugging .NET Project "Unable to start program"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug an application that I have occasionally in the past without problem.  I have a shared directory that I use for output on the remote machine, remote debugging tools are running on the machine and working fine.  The folder has "everyone" permissions to be sure.

When I rebuild, all output files are generated, including the one I'm trying to debug.  I'm then given an error,

**"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program
'D:\MyShare\MyApp.exe'.
The system cannot find the file specified"**

This is particularly odd because the file exists, it just created it, and I can execute it manually just fine, either locally, or on the remote machine.  I've checked with Process Monitor and that suggests the file is fine, so Visual Studio seems to be able to see the program just fine, not sure what's causing the error.

I've restarted both sides without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical, I resolve it just the second I post this...  The solution was to use the full UNC Share path, **not** the mapped drive path.

so my project 'Output Path' of

`d:\myshare\`

became

`\\somepc\myshare`

Now it all works as expected.

Comment: Do consider that this was caused by running Visual Studio elevated.  Drive mappings are a per-user setting and are not inherited when you elevate through the UAC consent prompt.  Running VS elevated is best avoided, but might be necessary in some cases.

Comment: I wasn't running in elevated, but I know the issue that you are referring to as I've also experienced that in the past, I thought this was the same, but it would do the same when running normally or elevated, maybe there's something odd about my mapped drive?